# Error in fitting a GEE model to a multinomial dataset using multgee package in R

Tags: r, multinomial

I am working on fitting a GEE model to a multinomial dataset [msm](https://github.com/chjackson/msm/blob/master/data/msmdata.rda) using the R package `multgee`. Stuck at the first step. I'm not sure if I fit the model correctly. Any help here would be appreciated. Thanks.

Partial data:
[image]

Code I tried:

```
library(multgee)

dat <- cav
newdata<- na.omit(dat)
new2<-newdata %>% mutate(ID = rowid(PTNUM))

fit<-ordLORgee(state~factor(years)+factor(age)+factor(dage)+factor(sex)+pdiag+factor(cumrej)+factor(firstobs)+statemax,data=new2,id=ID,repeated=state)

fit2<-ordLORgee(state~factor(years)+factor(age)+factor(dage)+factor(sex)+pdiag+factor(cumrej)+factor(firstobs)+statemax,data=new2,id=new2$ID,repeated=new2$state)
```

I got the same error below:

```
Error in ordLORgee(state ~ factor(years) + factor(age) + factor(dage) +  : 
  'repeated' does not have unique values per 'id'
```

Comment: I have no experience with this function but I would have guessed that the the correct column to offer as “id” would be “PTNUM”

Comment: Without knowing the internals of `ordLORgee`, the error indicates that variable *state* (used for the `repeated` argument) should be among all observations sharing the same *id* (= rownumber per PTNUM, in your case). This requirement is not met as you can check with `with(new2, table(PTNUM, state))`.